# Is it possible to know how much memory was used for a docker-compose run?

Tags: docker, docker-compose

I have a docker-compose configuration for which I'll like to know how much memory was used for a specific run, is there a way to do it?

Comment: Does this help you? https://github.com/docker/compose/issues/1197

Answer (score 1):

I have created a test container using below commands:

[image]

I created a new directory and created a file docker-compose.yml in it. When I will run docker-compose up from this directory, it will look for this specific file and create our deployment accordingly. Add the following contents inside this docker-compose.yml file.

[image]

The -d flag is added so that to run the container in background Now we can see the stats of the newly created container:

[image]

Comment: You seem to have included images in this answer where you have the commands to run and in other places.  This can be hard to search for, and some people won't be able to read them at all.  More practically, the asker can't copy and paste them into their own environment.  Can you edit this question to have actual text in place of the images?